# List comprehension of 2+ variables in R

Tags: python, r

What's the best R equivalent of the Python 2-variable list comprehension

```
[datetime(y,m,15) for y in xrange(2000,2020) for m in [3,6,9,12]]
```

The result

```
[datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 15, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2000, 6, 15, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2000, 9, 15, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 15, 0, 0), 
datetime.datetime(2001, 3, 15, 0, 0) ... ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will produce equivalent results in R

```
with(expand.grid(m=c(3,6,9,12), y=2000:2020), ISOdate(y,m,15))
```

We use `expand.grid` to get all combinations of year and month, and then we just use the vectorized `ISOdate` function to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to express the desired result using the listcompr package:

```
library(listcompr)
gen.list(ISOdate(y, m, 15), y = 2000:2019, m = c(3, 6, 9, 12))
```

Note that `range(a,b)` (or `xrange(a, b)` in Python2) is equivalent to `a:(b-1)` (stop element `b` excluded) in R (and not `a:b`, which includes the stop element).